# Integration of outlook into asp.net

Tags: asp.net, outlook

My requirement is Integration of outlook into my application.
Inorder to start the integration, first we are adding the COM library references of outlook into my referencs.

Actually my requirement is I dont know which version of outlook client has installed on his workstyation?
For my programming purpose if I add outtlook 2007 Dll (outlook 12.0 library) then the client who has outlook 2003 (outlook 11.0 library) can't access my application.It will throw exceptions.

How can I fix this problem?

Can I add outlook references dynamically  based on installed outlook version?

How to solve this please help me?

Answer (score 0):

With the System.Reflection namespace classes, [you can load DLL's dynamically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx). But then you have to do everything through reflection.

In your specific case, though, I would have all the references there statically (unless it's a huge load, to reference every available Outlook DLL). Then it gets down to properly using Design Patterns to use the right version for each situation your code will handle.